# trace route for WDS connected WIFI access points

Tags: wifi, networking, repeater

I have ADSL router ([WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system) enabled) and two repeaters to extend WiFi converge range.

When I try to do a tracert (windows), the first hop is the gateway directly (not the WDS access point).

Is there any tool which gives the details of the trip of packets inside the WDS enabled network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access points are layer 2 devices. Tracert works at layer 3. There's no way that I know of to trace the path through layer 2 devices.